# SOAP response get truncated for big payload

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, http-1.1, http-1.0

We have a legacy `SOAP web service`, implemented using `Apache Axis 1`. At the client environment, the response  data sometimes gets truncated on certain API calls causing error. But when tested using SOAP UI client, it returns full data as expected. This behavior can't be locally replicated in our dev environment and happens only at client office. They do have front end proxies and stuff in place to route the request.

We are still using `HTTP 1.0`. Will that be causing any issues with a big payload? How much effort will it take to upgrade to `HTTP 1.1`? Will it be a simple header upgrade stating `HTTP/1.1`?

We are already encoding the data using `utf-8` on request and response.

Sample SOAP request:

```
[POST /apixyzCall HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.1beta
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "http://abc/SoapManager"
Content-Length: 983

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>

PAYLOAD
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

]

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the issue was with SSL. The API returns complete data using HTTP, but it truncates response once SSL is enabled. It was closing the connection before the client receives the full response.

Comment: how you fixed this ?

Comment: @rinilnath   - We upgraded from http 1.0 to 1.1, switched to HttpClient from legacy java SSLSocket and it  resolved the problem.